# Are Type Attributes on SCRIPT, STYLE, and LINK elements still needed?

Tags: html, css, browser

You will see many sites with the following type of code:

Script elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //javascript here
</script>
```

Link elements:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="url.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Style elements:

```
<style type="text/css">
   /* CSS */
</style>
```

My question is this:

Are the `type` attributes needed in the popular browsers today?

(Popular meaning IE 8+, Firefox, Webkit, Opera and Chrome)

What happens if you *do not* include them?

Note: The answer needs to cover both HTML5 and XHTML doctypes if there is a difference in behavior between the two.

Comment: You ask a question about "type attributes" and then specify that "both HTML5 and XHTML _doctypes_" must be covered. These are two different things please clarfy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In short**, they are not required since **HTML5**, but are required by **W3C** standards in **HTML4/XHTML**.

---

In **HTML5** `type` of `script` tag:

> **type** - This attribute identifies the scripting language of code embedded
>   within a script element or referenced via the element’s src attribute.
>   This is specified as a MIME type; examples of supported MIME types
>   include text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/javascript, and
>   application/ecmascript. **If this attribute is absent, the script is
>   treated as JavaScript.**

in **HTML4** and **XHTML** it's required by [W3C standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html).

For `style` and `link` `type`:

> In **HTML5**, the type attribute is no longer required. **Default value is
>   "text/css".**

Comment: Note that the future might bring different defaults for HTML6. So make sure to indicate which HTML version (i.e. HTML5) you use, if you rely on these defaults.

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

No, they aren't.

## Long answer

For a long time, browser sets the default `type=text/javascript` at script elements, ect. when you omitted the `type` attribute. HTML5 makes this official, but every browser supported it long time ago.

In fact, which doctype you use isn't affecting the browsers behaviour, only the W3C specs. The nice and short HTML5 doctype is the standard doctype for years in normal browsers. HTML5 just makes those nice things official.

So you can use it and no browser will scream or fail, only the validator.

Answer (score 1):

In Newer browsers (supporting HTML5) type attrib is optional and if not given it *sctipt* will understand default as text/javascript and *style* will understand as text/css

Answer (score 1):

**They are currently not required**. Because all browsers assume the default that you would expect.

But they may become important in the **future**.

For example, when [Google Dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dart_%28programming_language%29) becomes fully integrated in the browsers, and we then *finally have an alternative to JavaScript*. Similarly, once someone proposes a nice replacement for CSS, we *will* need this. And it may well be that Dart becomes "JavaScript 2.0". And the bastard language that JavaScript is surely needs a more sane replacement. I guess we are all only using it, because there is no alternative that works cross-browser (and in fact, not even one that works in a single browser, I guess ...).

So if you plan your site to live for a year: don't bother. If you plan to have the site running for 10 years, try to be verbose about your content types, formats and versions.

Comment: Interesting thought but in 10 years I assume I will re-do/re-make my site in that time frame. You mention Google Dart, it sounds like that it is not *when* it becomes fully integrated but *if* it becomes fully integrated. Time will tell. Thanks!

Comment: Well, given that Google *owns* one of the most popular browsers, they sure have a chance to get it at least into one of them anytime soon.

Comment: That is true, I do not have an opinion one way or another.